# Ruby debugger crashes on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, crash

I'm encountering a weird problem on Windows with the ruby debuger right now.
In order for me to not retype the whole issue, here is the link to the problem:
http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/7a7fbd456c4a7740

Anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

Well the bigger issue is you're developing with RoR on Windows :)

Why do you have both ruby-debug gems in your gem list? You only need "ruby-debug19" for ruby 1.9.2+, so you can take out "ruby-debug".

Don't know if that will fix your problem, but give it a try.